# How to retrieve the company information with the Autodesk ID?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I would like to get the same information as CSV that can be exported in BIM360 Document Management using the Issue API.
Most of the information can be obtained by calling the Issue API or another API using the ID that can be obtained from the Issue API, but I cannot get the company information when the assignedToType is "company".

[The Issue API returns an "Autodesk ID"](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/issues-v2-issues-issueId-GET/#:%7E:text=assignedTo,type%20(assignedToType).), which is about 9 digits, but [the API to retrieve company](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/companies-GET/) requires a different ID, "company id", and even if all companies are retrieved, there is no key for the Autodesk ID in them, so it cannot be searched.

Is there any way to retrieve the company information with Autodesk ID?

Comment: The id for company with Admin API is member_group_id. It is true it is confusing. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @XiaodongLiang I found that key and my code worked as I expected. Thank you so much for answering my question!